# Show field's help text on node page

Tags: 7, entities

I'd like to achieve the following:

I'd like to give help text for a field in a content type, and I would like to show that help text on the node page as well.

I've looked at `$content` in `page.tpl.php` and `$variables` in `theme_field()` but these variables doesn't seem to contain these help texts.

How can I make these help texts appear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get access to help by use [field_info_instance](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_instance/7) function in Your template.php

At the beginning let's assume that You have a field called '**spagetti**' created in content type '**Article**'. Also,  in this case, **mytheme** is Your default theme.

First, edit mytheme's template.php file and put into following code:

```
/**
* Implements template_preprocess_field
*/
function mytheme_preprocess_field(&$variables) {
  $field_name = $variables['element']['#field_name'];
  if($field_name == 'field_spagetti') {
    //Get help ('description' parameter) of field Spagetti
    $instance = field_info_instance('node', $field_name, 'article');
    //Add new parameter to the field
    $variables['element']['#help'] = $instance['description'];
  }
}
```

Now You can get help value from field array.

For example You may to create template for field spagetti: 
(field--field-spagetti.tpl.php) 
and render field inside:

```
$field = $variables['element'];

echo $field['#title'];
echo $field['#items'][0]['value'];
echo $field['#help'];
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Don't forget to [handle the description in a secure fashion](https://www.drupal.org/node/28984)! For example, `check_plain($instance['description']);`.